# Change input value on button click with PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, web

I have an html button which call a php function on click , and this function change the value of a variable , and beside the button i have a text which display the value of this variable , my question is how can i change immediatly the value and be displayed in the html page ( for example i have the current value '9' , but when i click on button i want it to be 'voila' as done in function ) , i've read that i can do it with AJAX but i dont know how exactly , any help will be appreciated

**The Button**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onClick="generer()">Generate</button>
```

**The display input**

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item disabled"><?php echo $password; ?></a>
```

**The PHP code**

```
<?php
 $password = "9";
 function generer(){
           $password = "voila";
        }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not call a php function from html. You will need javascript for that.

There are 2 possible solutions -

1. Write your function in js like

```js
 function generer(){
           document.getElementById("generated").innerHTML = "voila";
        }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onClick="generer()">Generate</button>

<a href="#" id="generated" class="list-group-item disabled">9</a>
```

2. If you must handle something on the server with php. You will need to make a separate php script where you will generate the value and return it, then make an AJAX request(as you mentioned) again via JS to retrieve that value and change html. Like this

assuming you created generator.php file and put your generation logic in it, this will be your js function

```
    function generer() {
       var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById("generated").innerHTML = this.responseText;
         }
       };
       xmlhttp.open("GET", "generator.php", true);
       xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that's what i was looking for

Comment: You are welcome. But as @charlietfl mentioned it is very basic staff. You need to understand it not just copy pasting. Here is a good entry point for that  [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: Yes but just to clarify things , im an AI engineer and i dont work with Javascript and AJAX so much , i have to complete a task today and i had no choice but to find a fast way to do it , because my problem is not much JS or PHP stuff , its more a backend that i will have a lot to work on it now

Answer (score 0):

```js
function generer(){ $("#gen_value").html("voila"); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onClick="generer()">Generate</button>
<a href="#" id="gen_value" class="list-group-item disabled">9</a>
```

>

Comment: The question asked for help learning how to use AJAX, which isn't what you've done. If AJAX truly isn't necessary, please include an explanation why.

Comment: This wasnt really what i asked but Thank you man it's a good solution too

Comment: You can't call a PHP function from html for this because you want to change a tag value by button click event, which is possible by AJAX call. So you can try it once its working.